# How to look at a file in the latest master?

Tags: git

I am working on master branch, but have not done rebasing for a long time.

I wonder where master branch is up to, and interested in the latest development progress of a file in particular.

Is there a way to see the latest revision of a file on origin master, without rebasing my workspace?

Comment: why are you working on master? that is probably not the best way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
git show COMMITISH:path/to/file
```

to see the contents of a file at a particular commit or branch.  In your case, it would look something like:

```
git show origin/master:path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pull master into to a new branch

```
git checkout -b master_preview
git pull origin master

#diff the branches
git diff master

#clean up when finished
git checkout master
git branch -d master_preview
```

Comment: I don't think the first two lines will do the RIght Thing in this case. I'd do `git fetch origin ; git checkout -b master_preview origin/master` (if I would do it that way at all - see answer of +jszakmeister).

Answer (score 0):

Use this for graphical diff of your file in your master branch vs upstream:

```
git difftool origin/master master -- file
```

On Linux it works best if `meld` is installed.